# Cross database permissions through stored procedure permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have a stored procedure set up in `DATABASE1` that among other things makes a call to a stored procedure call `sp_start_job` (this is a stored procedure in the msdb database that will fire off an agent job).

I have created a proxy login and mapped this login to user accounts in **msdb** and **DATABASE1** databases.

In my original stored procedure, I am using EXEC as proxylogin. This proxy user has rights to execute this procedure and in the msdb database can execute the sp_start_job procedure and is additionally a member of the SqlAgentOperator,SqlAgentUser, and SqlAgentReader Roles. I have also given the user in **DATABASE1** AND **msdb** authenicate permissions.

The idea is that any user that can execute the original procedure will actually run it under the proxylogin's credentials so I do not have to assign these permissions out. I am still running into permission error, does anyone have insight into this problem?

Comment: have you tried explicitly granting the user permissions to execute, directly on the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got around this by turning cross database ownership chaining on